# What's the issue with the "->" lamda operator when coding in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, closures

Messing about with a JavaFX I write this:

```
    MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Item 1")
    menuItem1.setOnAction(e -> {
        println "Menu Item 1 Selected"
    })
```

This gives an error in Eclipse: "Groovy:expecting ')' found '->'"

```
    MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Item 1")
    menuItem1.setOnAction({ e -> 
        println "Menu Item 1 Selected $e"
    })
```

This works fine. As does this:

```
    menuItem1.onAction = { e ->
        println "Menu Item 1 Selected $e"
    }
```

The first way is the way you would do it in Java8+.  Why does Groovy say that that is illegal, and is there any difference in terms of use or scope of the variable `e` in the above two/three ways of doing things?

Comment: Well ... [Groovy is not Java](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a difference between Java and Groovy.  Groovy has closures basically since the beginning - Java added lambdas in JDK8.

From the [docs](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_lambdas):

> Java 8 supports lambdas and method references:
>
> ```
> Runnable run = () -> System.out.println("Run");
> list.forEach(System.out::println);
> ```
>
> Java 8 lambdas can be more or less considered as anonymous inner classes. Groovy doesn’t support that syntax, but has closures instead:
>
> ```
> Runnable run = { println 'run' }
> list.each { println it } // or list.each(this.&println)
> ```

Comment: Groovy 3.0's new parser (currently not in final release) works with Java's lambda syntax

Comment: Interested to learn about Groovy 3.0, thanks Tim.  @cfrick Thanks... just not quite clear *why* the lamda syntax is illegal in Groovy... but the explanation is probably too involved!

Comment: Because the parser does not support it (yet, the parrot (or what's it called nowadays?) parser in 3 (and most likely optionally in 2.6) seems to support it.

Comment: Groovy had closures since its inception (Java 5?). When Java got lambdas, they were a different format, so the antlr3 groovy parser couldn't parse them. But for groovy 3, Daniel Sun and others have reworked the parser to handle them, as well as loads of other improvements http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#Groovy3.0releasenotes-Parrot